# How to access Object.field in criteria in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, properties, hibernate-criteria

i have write the criteria for company class. 
below are company class, companySearch class and criteria. But criteria list is throw exception. exception is "org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: san.san of: com.sesami.common.domain.Company". How to access Company.san.san?

#### Company class

```
public class Company extends DomainObject implements UserDetails {
private Long id;
private String companyName;
private CompanyType companyType;
private String description;
private String companyURL;
private String billToEmail;
private String hashPassword;
private SAN san;

@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
public SAN getSan() {
    return san;
}

public void setSan(SAN san) {
    this.san = san;
}
...
}
```

#### CompanySearch

```
public class CompanySearch {
private String companyName;
private String email;
private Long san;
private String gstNumber;
......
public Long getSan() {
    return san;
}

public void setSan(Long san) {
    this.san = san;
}
...
}
```

#### Criteria

```
companyCriteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(
            Company.class);

    if (companySearch.getSan() != null
            && !"".equals(companySearch.getSan()))
        companyCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("san.san",
                companySearch.getSan()));

    Integer count = ((Long) companyCriteria.setProjection(
            Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult()).intValue();
    companyCriteria.setProjection(null);
    companyCriteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ROOT_ENTITY);
    companyCriteria
            .setFirstResult((pager.getPage() - 1) * pager.getPageSize())
            .setMaxResults(pager.getPageSize()).list();
    List<Company> companies = companyCriteria.list();

    PagedResultSet pr = new PagedResultSet();
    pr.setPager(pager);
    pr.setResultSet(companies);
    pr.setRowCount(count);
    return pr;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must create a join to the San entity, using a subcriteria, or an alias:

```
companyCriteria.createAlias("san", "sanAlias"); 
companyCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("sanAlias.san",
                    companySearch.getSan()));
```

or

```
companyCriteria.createCriteria("san").add(Restrictions.eq("san",
                                          companySearch.getSan()));
```

This is well explained in the [Hibernate reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-associations) and even in the [Criteria javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html).

Note that this has absolutely nothing to do with Spring, and everything to do with Hibernate. If you searched in the Spring doc for how to do this, no wonder you didn't find anything.